# Android missing Google Play Services library

Tags: android, google-maps

I was at a point in development in my Android app to where I thought a nice implementation of the Google Maps API might suite my users well.

Come to find out, that my SDK Manager needed a lot of installed updates, one of which is necessary for the Google Maps API V2. The package is called Google Play Services and inside that installation is a library you import to your work-space to use in your application which allows me to develop my Google Maps API implementation.

I installed and updated Google Play Services and went to import the needed library into my work-space when behold it is not there.

The folder structure goes:
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-19-1\libs

Inside libs are three jars: effects, maps, and usb

When I go to import the library Eclispe wont let me as a library is not there!

Please help, I feel as if my situation is simple and I am just overlooking the obvious. Pleas and thank you!

Comment: I think you can directly add google play services project as a library project, instead of jar.

Comment: But where is the library, or is it suppose to be a jar? Either way Eclispe import system will not allow me to import anything from that directory.

Comment: just paste that google library to where your project located actually, means in same workspace first and then import.

Answer (score 0):

Once you install google play services you need to import to let Eclipse know. You go to File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Code and import without copying to workbench. Then in your project you select Properties and add library to your project in Android pane.